# Program crashes when prompting user for input

Tags: c

I made a simple little program and it crashes before it gets to the part of the if statement.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100];
    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s\n",name);
    printf("You are trapped in a tunnel. Go through the right doors to get out\n");

    int choice;

    printf("Choose door 1 or door 2");
    scanf("%d", choice);
    if (choice == 1){
        printf("This is the correct door");
    }

    else if (choice == 2){
        printf("This is the wrong door");
    }

    else{
        printf("Press 1 or 2");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My program runs fine with no errors, it just crashes...

Comment: `scanf("%d", choice); `should be `scanf("%d", &choice);`

Comment: You probably forgot to enable format-string warnings (e.g. `-Wformat` in GCC).  If your compiler doesn't provide an option for that, seriously consider upgrading!

Comment: You should enable all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and improve your code to get no warnings... Then you should **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch or use an IDE ;)

Comment: The IDE is not a compiler. It just runs one. So better know how to run the compiler

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d", &choice);`

This is how it was meant to be. `choice` is a standalone `int`, so you need to pass its address to `scanf` to get correct results. What you do now is passing a value that is stored in `choice` to `scanf`, while it expects an address.

Answer (score 0):

> The C library function `int scanf(const char *format, ...)` reads
>   formatted input from stdin.

So it should be like this:

```
int choice;

printf("Choose door 1 or door 2");
scanf("%d", &choice); //& means the address-of
if (choice == 1){
    printf("This is the correct door");
}

else if (choice == 2){
    printf("This is the wrong door");
}

else{
    printf("Press 1 or 2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss `&` in `scanf` statement that why it doesn't working.. 
It should be

```
scanf("%d",&choice);
```